# Will rviz2 work on windows10

Tags: ros2, rviz, ros-humble, windows10

I installed ROS2 humble version in windows following the steps in the ros website.I installed windows10 in virtual box. I was not able to run rviz in windows..I wanted to know whether rviz is supported in windows..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: when i tried to run rviz in windows10,it is showing some errors which i asked in my previous questions..But no one responded..plz try to look my previous question..I have attached the error in it..

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! IMHO, using ROS on Windows 10 inside VirtualBox is not a recommended setup. The graphics inside VirtualBox may break RViz, and you may have to spend hours making those graphics work. On the other hand, why don't you install ROS directly on your OS without VirtuaalBox?